# Kotlin coroutine - When i update a text view from another thread the app does not crush

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.download.setOnClickListener {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                delay(3000)
                Log.i(TAG, Thread.currentThread().name)
                binding.text.text = "Downloaded"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat printed:** I/MainActivity: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1

I should get a *crash* because I try to update the text view from another thread, but i don't. Why?

Comment: I think we need to see your entire stack trace.

Comment: There is no stack trace. My app just working, the text is updated if i press the button

Comment: See https://medium.com/@dimezis/how-android-8-lets-you-get-away-with-touching-views-from-any-thread-906419b368fa